# Parse Groups Meeting Certain Conditions from String

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I am trying to parse out to groups of numerics that match a certain criteria.

**Text Sample**

```
KBOS 052354Z 19012KT 10SM FEW075 BKN110 OVC200 24/14 A2975 RMK AO2 SLP074 T02390144 10289 20239 55002
```

**Needed groups to be parsed**

```
10289 20239
```

**Attempted Code**

```
echo "KBOS 052354Z 19012KT 10SM FEW075 BKN110 OVC200 24/14 A2975 RMK AO2 SLP074 T02390144 10289 20239 55002" | grep -E '^1[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
echo "KBOS 052354Z 19012KT 10SM FEW075 BKN110 OVC200 24/14 A2975 RMK AO2 SLP074 T02390144 10289 20239 55002" | grep -E '^2[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to match only at the start of the string with `^` anchor at the start. Besides, you are not extracting matches, you only get the lines matching the pattern.

Use

```
grep -oE '\b[12][0-9]{4}\b'
```

It will fetch you the matched substrings only thanks to `-o` and the pattern will only match

- `\b` - word boundary
- `[12]` - `1` or `2`
- `[0-9]{4}` - any four digits
- `\b` - word boundary.

See an [online `grep` demo](https://ideone.com/isFrEG):

```
s="KBOS 052354Z 19012KT 10SM FEW075 BKN110 OVC200 24/14 A2975 RMK AO2 SLP074 T02390144 10289 20239 55002"
grep -oE '\b[12][0-9]{4}\b' <<< "$s"
# Or grep -oE '\<[12][0-9]{4}\>' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
10289
20239
```

Comment: Thank you Wiktor! This is precisely what I was looking for